# Get userdata session in database.php file in codeigniter 3

Tags: mysql, session, codeigniter-3

I am using CI Version 3.1.0 and I want to use session in database.php file.

I set session using below code:

```
$newdata = array('name' => $udata[0]['name'], 
                 'id' => $udata[0]['id'],
                 'useremail' => $udata[0]['email_id'],
                 'is_superadmin' => $udata[0]['is_superadmin'],
                 'db_name' => $udata[0]['db_name'],
                 'db_user' => $udata[0]['db_user'],
                 'active' => TRUE);
                 $this->session->set_userdata($this->lang->line('common_admin_session_label'), $newdata);
```

And it is working correctly.

Now My code which I use in `database.php` file is below :

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->load->library('session');
$ses = $CI->session->userdata;
print_r($ses); die;
```

Which gives me an error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Dashboard::$session

Filename: config/database.php

Line Number: 82

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tops_libraries_new\trunk\application\config\database.php
Line: 82
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tops_libraries_new\trunk\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I have also load libraries, drivers, and packages in the `autoload.php` file

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','pagination');
$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');
$autoload['packages'] = array('database','form_validation','session','email');
```

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Thank You.

Comment: WHY ?? **Now My code which i use in `database.php` file is below :**

Comment: I want to use dynamic database collection using logged in user's database name (SAAS model)

Answer (score 0):

We can overwrite `config` values from controller via `$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');`

For Example:

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', $this->session->userdata('youritem'));
```

if there's `$config['item_name'] = 'testVal';` in the `config` using `$this->config->item('item_name')` will be '`testVal`'

I hope this will help you..thanks!

Comment: Thanks abdul , i did this too it is set successfully but when i print CI instance in database file i will not get that parameter as set, actually it is set by your method.

Comment: Can u pls explain your requirement?

Comment: I have SAAS model , every user who logged in have different database and i want to set that database name and user name in database.php file dynamically.